# sh: ng: command not found Failed to exec start script on openshift while deploying

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, openshift

I hit the below error on container when i deploy the app on Open shift.

status of container is  Crash Loop Back-off

Local env works fine with no errors.

I made sure angular package versions are aligned to get the build successful.

```
> ng serve

sh: ng: command not found
npm info lifecycle dashboard@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! dashboard@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dashboard@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm timing npm Completed in 122ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /opt/app-root/src/.npm/_logs/2020-04-10T15_14_11_050Z-debug.log
```

My package.json looks like below

```
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "7.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^13.0.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "sessionstorage": "^0.1.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.26",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.26",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.59",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Any thoughts or help is appreciated.

Comment: Add npm install -g @anguarl/cli before running ng serve!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `npx` before `ng serve` like this `npx ng serve`

If you have installed the dependencies locally and need to refer those packages instead of global. use `npx` before the the command eg: `npx ng serve` refers to the locally installed package. `ng serve` refers to the global package.

npm version 5.2+